# How to parse the DOM of a page on another domain

Tags: html, ajax, json, jquery

I've been having a lot of trouble parsing the DOM of a remote webpage using AJAX. I don't seem to be able to find any example or tutorials demonstrating this procedure.

I basically want to search through the DOM of a remote page, find a tag with a specific id/class, take the inner contents of that tag and print it out on my own page.

If anyone can help i'd appreciate it.

Comment: What's the problem? Getting the data? Constructing the DOM? Searching it? Break down the problem, don't look for a magic bullet for the overarching situation. As it stands, the question is overly broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same-origin-policy browsers have do not allow you to access external pages for security reasons. You need to use e.g. a PHP script on your server to retrieve the external site's HTML. Then you can make an AJAX call to that script instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use this: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

Easy to use.